# Set basename with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using **react-router** and in that, I am using **hashRouter**. Now i have to **deploy my react app in sub-directory** of my website. So for that, I did:

1) Added homepage parameter in `package.json` file
2) Added `<HashRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>`

Now, When I access my website URL `localhost/react`, I will be redirected to  `http://localhost/#/react/apps/`.

But I want it to be redirected to `http://localhost/react/#/apps/`.

**Note:** I have to deploy react production build.

**My production build structure:**

```
--- static
--- asset-manifest.json
--- index.html
--- manifest.json
--- service-worker.js
```

Please help me, How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for basename, it appends the string after the hash symbol:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter/basename-string

If you remove basename, and your index.html is served from /reactapp - it may just work.

Comment: I need to deploy my react production build inside sub-directory of server root. Means my domain will be www.domain.com/reactapp.

Comment: What is your folder structure ? Can you share folder structure and package. Json

Comment: Please make a look at my updated question to see production build folder structure. But how should i share my package.json with you?

Comment: If you can would be nice or because need to check did you specify a path to deploy

Comment: yes, I specified the homepage parameter in the package.json

Comment: Can you console log the process.env.public_url and check what is it return and the code is in react folder and path is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190211/discussion-between-rajat-and-dwarka-tiwari).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I resolved it by using hashrouter and giving '/reactApp' as basename.

my url becomes
http://localhost/reactApp#/apps/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).