# Deploy a React app to a subdirectory using HashRouter and Traefik

Tags: reactjs, nginx, traefik

I have a problem that is: I can't serve a react app in a sub-directory using HashRouter. I already tried the solutions proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208238/set-basename-with-react-router/55209170) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666895/react-doesnt-work-with-path-and-prefix-in-traefik) questions but it doesn't work as expected.

I have the following architecture:

- Traefik as reverse-proxy

```
  foo-service:
    image: foo
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.foo.rule=Host(`foo.localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/bar`)"
      # The line below is done in order to nginx to serve the files on the root 
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.pathStrip.stripprefix.prefixes=/bar"
      - "traefik.http.routers.foo.middlewares=pathStrip@docker"
```

- nginx serving a React App (that uses HashRouter)

  The problem here is that on `package.json` when I use `"homepage": "."` and I enter `foo.localhost/bar` I get a lot of 404 errors because the links to resources such as js/css are located on `./static/css/...css` instead of `bar/static/css/...css`.

  When I put `"homepage": "/bar"` the resources are loaded correctly but the URL becomes `foo.localhost/bar#/login` which seems wrong.

  And finally when I set both `"homepage": "/bar"` and `<HashRouter basename={'/bar'}>` the resources are also loaded correctly but then the URL becomes `foo.localhost/bar#/bar/login` which is a disaster.

I know that my second solution is "apparently" the closest one to the right solution but I honestly dislike it because setting the path on `package.json` seems bad to me. I would like to only change the reverse-proxy configuration instead and let the app be "agnostic".

Thanks in advance.